# Mdframed and monochrome

Tags: mdframed, backgrounds

When I use the monochrome option with the article class, the background of the mdframed frames is completely black. Is it a bug or just my misuse of the monochrome option?

```
\documentclass{article}
%\documentclass[monochrome]{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\begin{document}

Some text. {\color{blue!45}This text is blue (or black if the monochrome option is specified)}

\begin{mdframed}
    More text
\end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

**Without monochrome:**
[image: Without monochrome]

**With monochrome:**
[image: With monochrome]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the standard `framemethod` the background is basically one large `\rule` whose color is changed to `white` by default. If you disable colors with the `monochrome` option this rule gets black.

You could use the tikz framemethod instead. And consider to switch to tcolorbox which is much more flexible and stable than mdframed.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[monochrome]{xcolor}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}

\begin{document}

{\color{white}\rule{2cm}{2cm}} %black with monochrome.

Some text. {\color{blue!45}This text is blue (or black if the monochrome option is specified)}

\begin{mdframed}
    More text
\end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the precision which explains why the background is black and for the solution with framemethod=tikz which I will adopt for the moment. I will switch to tcolorbox for my next documents.

I notice that you use the monochrome option when loading the xcolor package instead of using it as an option when declaring the class of the document; Is it equivalent or is one better than the other?